# Typescript: strange behavior on validating function return object type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I discovered that my return type are not validated as expected by typescript when I use the `const myFn: () => MyObjType` notation. Here is a relevant [ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiDyAjAVlAvFA3gKCnqAhgPwBcUAzsAE4CWAdgOa76KlR0CuAtohFdgF9s2AMYB7OpSgAzOuhkc6I4DQlQAFAEoycJKhz4oVCMA5U5Bw-gJkA5JVqNbAGmZWKACzEcANgBMAUSoqOz4qFzcoISFsaUVlVTlZACYtHQQULEjjU3Ms9zwbKHtqegYIgs9vfyCQ4rCK-GjhcUlgGToAZjItdAA%20WAzUDF60AfVLQrsHMsa8ci9fQODQ4IiBTRaJKVkAFh7NfsG9eTilFTVe-PwcswtIwyKSx3LXSoXq5brbBremwSAA) and the code:

```js
type MyObj = {
    a?: string
    b?: number
}

const fn = function (): MyObj {
    return {
        a: 'string',
        shouldErr: 'err', // has error
    }
}

function fn2(): MyObj {
    return {
        a: 'string',
        shouldErr: 'err', // has error
    }
}

const fn3: () => MyObj = () => ({
    a: 'string',
    shouldErr: 'err', // has NO ERROR
})

const fn4: () => MyObj = function ()  {
    return {
        a: 'string',
        shouldErr: 'err',  // has NO ERROR
    }
}
```

In my code, the typings can be simplified as:

```js
type MyComplexObj = {
  myFn(): ReturnType
}
```

So I am not sure on my options to obtain the behavior I expect.

Could you explain why return types are validated like this? Is there a way to get around this and "strictly" validate return type so that, in the previous example, the `shouldErr` prop is in error ?

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code or other text. Copy the original text to the question (+ format properly)

Comment: This is effectively a current limitation in TS; see [ms/TS#12632](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12632) and the info in the linked question/answer

Answer (score 2):

The type

```
type MyObj = {
    a?: string
    b?: number
}
```

includes

```
return {
    a: 'string',
    shouldErr: 'err',  // has NO ERROR
}
```

When you specify the exact return type of a function, you get an error. The same would happen if you specified it in the 2 examples below:

```
const fn3: () => MyObj = (): MyObj => ({
    a: 'string',
    shouldErr: 'err', // will show an error now
})
```